# How to get video length of a youtube video in drupal7

Tags: views, 7, services, files

I created a node in drupal7 which contains a youtube link. I installed `youtube module` in my site. with the help of this module i just created a field for inputting url to youtube video.
every thing worked fine. It is showing me the thumbnail,video etc. 
But the problem is how to get the `length of the youtube video` ?

I am using `views` to generate a json web service the output is

```
{
            "title":"social networking",
            "field_eventcat":"Performing Arts",
            "field_eventdaytime":"06\/06\/2012 - 05:00",
            "field_eventvideos":"http:\/\/sample sites\/sites\/default\/files\/styles\/thumbnail\/public\/youtube\/6a_KF7TYKVc.png",
            "nid":"34"
         }
```

I want to get the video lenght with this object. pls help

Comment: you are using the media_youtube module? Which youtube module are you using?

Comment: @Dipen I used http://drupal.org/project/youtube module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow the function [youtube_get_remote_image](http://drupalcode.org/project/youtube.git/blob/bb9d3f959ed460e2c0910a10a2ca2cd648a58948:/youtube.inc#l41) on how to make a call to youtube api and retrieve video length.

Youtube public api provides this info without any authentication, for instance - http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dc4UltkRJsw contains video length in the tag: yt:duration. I have not tested the below function, but should work.

```
function youtube_get_video_length($id = NULL) {
  $path = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $id;
  $query = array(
   'v' => '2',
   'alt' => 'jsonc'
 );
  $url = url($path, array('query' => $query));
  $result = drupal_http_request($url);
  $data = json_decode($result->data);
  $video_length = $data->data->duration;
  return $video_length;
 }
```

Also I dont suggest that you write this in youtube.inc of youtube module, write in your custom module or template.php of custom theme.

Hope that helps.